# How change the pagination url in .htaccess

Tags: pagination

i am new to .htaccess an i want to know how to change the following url.

```
fun.php?search=&submit=search&page=2
```

Int to this

```
fun/page/2
```

Comment: Shouldn't that include the search text, like `fun/page/2?search=...` (or `fun/.../page/2`, which I feel is wrong)?

Comment: Anyway: you'll have to look into Apache's mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

I think it cannot be done in a direct way. Php GET method is needed to pass variables to the php code. However, you can add "fun" directory,add "page" directory, add "2" directory and add 2.php into your page directory with this code

```
   <?php
   header('Location:http://yourweb/fun.php?search=&submit=search&page=2');
   ?>
```

add a .htaccess file into "2" directory with this code

```
  DirectoryIndex 2.php
```

That's all. Remember, php get method variable is not mean't to be shortened. Instead, use POST method

Hope it works

Comment: Thanks for your asnwer Poomrokc. I dont want to change it in php but only in httacces,

Like this or something like this

    RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite all php files    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

# Rewrite blog pagination
RewriteRule ^fun/page/([a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]?) fun.php?search=&submit=search&page=$1 [L,QSA]



Thanks.

Comment: All right , Im not a big fan off .htaccess so I really look forward for someone to answer this. :)